# How do i only allow yes or no for this question

Tags: c

I am trying to allow only `yes` or `no` and exit problem if the answer is either number of other letters. How am I supposed to add it?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char answer;
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    if (answer == 'y') {
        printf("You Entered: 'y'\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("your turn\n");
        printf("\n");
    }
    else if (answer == 'n') {
        printf("You Entered: 'n'");
        printf("\n");
        printf("other's turn\n");
        printf("\n");
    }
    else (answer != 'y' && answer != 'n'); {
        if (answer == '%d') {
            printf("You Entered:  '%d'\n", answer);
            printf("You did not enter 'y' or 'n', program now exiting... \n");
    
            if (answer <= 'A' || answer <='a') {
                printf("You Entered:  '%c'\n", answer);
                printf("You did not enter 'y' or 'n', program now exiting... \n");  
    
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just remove the conditions of the third case. If the code goes to the else case, you already know that it is neither 'y' nor 'n', so you don't need to add more testing there.

Comment: The condition `answer == '%d'` makes no sense, and is implementation dependent (multi-character literals are implementation defined). If you want to use a single input for different hings, read a whole line as a string, the try to parse the string to see what it contains.

Comment: Did you copy and paste that code? I don't see how it would compile. `'%d'` is not valid. You don't have an `if` after the second `else` so the code on that line after it does nothing. Finally, because of the missing `if`, the last block of code will always be executed.

Comment: Once you start using this code in a larger program, you're going to want to replace `scanf("%c", &answer);` with `scanf(" %c", &answer);`.  (Exercise 1: spot the difference.  Exercise 2 (harder): Why?)

Comment: What on earth do you expect this line to do? `else (answer != 'y' && answer != 'n'); {`

Comment: The two consecutive lines `else (answer != 'y' && answer != 'n'); {` and `if (answer == '%d') {` are mysterious (as [klutt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6699433/klutt) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75347804/how-do-i-only-allow-yes-or-no-for-this-question#comment132953464_75347804)).  You evaluate an expression and ignore the result completely in the `else` line (was that meant to be `else if` — if so, the semicolon is an interloper that is unwanted.  And the comparison with `'%d'` won't work (it will always be false).  It isn't remotely clear what you intended here.

Answer (score 1):

You already made an `if` block, which will check that the condition

`answer == 'y'`

is met, then after that there is an `else if`

`else if(answer == 'n')`

which will execute **ONLY** if the previous `if` statement's condition was not satisfied, **AND** based on the condition that you set, in this case:

`answer == 'n'`

Now, if you want to throw an error each and every time the user inputs anything different than those two values, there's no simpler solution than this one: making an `else` statement.

The `else` statement will execute **ONLY** if all other previous `if`s and `else if`s aren't executed.

Your final code could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char answer;
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    
    if(answer == 'y') {
        printf("You Entered: 'y'\n");
        printf("your turn\n\n");
    }
    else if(answer == 'n') {
        printf("You Entered: 'n'\n");
        printf("other's turn\n\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("You entered neither 'y' nor 'n', program will now exit...\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code have two problems:

1. You are missing a parenthesis at the last of your code and other small errors.
2. `if (answer == '%d')` this comparison is invalid.

   `%d` is a format specifier, so it cannot store any value.

After correcting your code, it should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char answer;
    scanf("%c", &answer);

    if (answer == 'y') {
        printf("You Entered: 'y'\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("your turn\n");
        printf("\n");
    }
    else if (answer == 'n') {
        printf("You Entered: 'n'");
        printf("\n");
        printf("other's turn\n");
        printf("\n");
    }
    else if (answer != 'y' && answer != 'n') {
        printf("You Entered:  '%d'\n", answer);
        printf("You did not enter 'y' or 'n', program now exiting... \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helped you out.

Comment: Nitpick: `scanf()` lacks error checking.

Answer (score 0):

*A* solution to this is to break the check out into a separate function which can read in a character and return `true` or `false` depending on whether the character read is one of `'y'` or `'n'`.

The return of this can then be checked in `main` and acted on accordingly.

In this case a conditional without `else` acts as a sentinel that prevents control flow from continuing by returning `1` if `get_yes_or_no` returns `false`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool get_yes_or_no(char *ch) {
    if (scanf("%c", ch) == 1 && (*ch == 'y' || *ch == 'n')) 
        return true;

    return false;   
}

int main(void) {
    char answer;

    if (!get_yes_or_no(&answer)) {
        printf("You Entered:  '%d'\n", answer);
        printf("You did not enter 'y' or 'n', program now exiting... \n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (answer == 'y') {
        printf("You Entered: 'y'\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("your turn\n");
        printf("\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("You Entered: 'n'");
        printf("\n");
        printf("other's turn\n");
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should output the invalid entered character as `'%c'` instead of `'%d'`

Comment: @chqrlie That would hide the value of non-printable `char` values.  For printable characters, I'd say print the printable `char` along with the `int` value.  For non-printable, maybe a table of things like `"VT"` or `"CR"` to go with the `int` value.

Comment: @chqrlie, I chose not to modify that apsect of the OP's code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: you are correct. It is also debatable whether the input should use `scanf(" %c", ch)` ignoring whitespace. Also note that `answer` remains uninitialized in case `stdin` is redirected from an empty file.

Comment: @Chris: *that aspect* refers to the OP's failing attempt at determining whether the user typed a number or some other string.

Comment: @chqrlie I suspect there might be other questions and answers on this site that go over the failings of `scanf()` in great detail... ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: `scanf()` is a inexhaustible source of questions and answers indeed :)